# What can be done with an imported .php (or any other file) in less?

Tags: html, css, less

I was wondering what I can do with an imported .php, .xml, etc. file in less? How can I use them? Is there any documentation? I have only found an explanation of the existence but not exactly how it can be used/works.

Comment: In short: nothing. Less can only understand CSS and Less itself.

Comment: Alright, thanks. It really confused me when I saw @import example.php.

Comment: Where exactly did you see that?

Comment: In the documentation it says: @import "foo.php";  // foo.php imported as a less file. That confused me as I didn't really understand what I can do afterwards with the php file (imported as less file).

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature-file-extensions):

> @import statements may be treated differently by Less depending on the
>   file extension:
>
> If the file has a .css extension it will be treated as CSS and the
>   @import statement left as-is (see the inline option below). **If it has
>   any other extension it will be treated as Less and imported.** If it
>   does not have an extension, .less will be appended and it will be
>   included as a imported Less file.